# FeinCMS: Get property of subsequent content block in template

Tags: django, django-templates, feincms

How can I get information about the subsequent FeinCMS content block in a template rendering a `RichTextContent`?

Obtaining something like the class name would be ideal, but also access to fields of the model would help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out-of-the-box here's no way to look ahead to the next content block. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

We often had to wrap multiple content blocks of the same type in another `<div>` with a certain class. We accomplished this with a custom templatetag (using the [django-ttag library](http://pythonhosted.org/django-ttag/)):

```
import ttag 
from feincms.templatetags.feincms_tags import _render_content                             

@register.tag                                                                             
class CmsRenderRegion(ttag.Tag):                                                          
    '''                                                                                   
    Renders a FeinCMS template region, just like feincms.templatetags.feincms_tags.render_region.
    However, it checks each content type for a field "wrapper_css_classes". If the content type
    has such a class, it adds a surrounding <div class="{{ wrapper_css_classes }}"> to all sequential 
    content types with that class.                                                        
    '''                                                                                   
    page = ttag.Arg()                                                                     
    region = ttag.Arg()                                                                   
    request = ttag.Arg()                                                                  

    def render(self, context):                                                            
        data = self.resolve(context)                                                      

        s = u''                                                                           
        last_wrapper = None                                                               
        for content in getattr(data['page'].content, data['region']):                     
             current_wrapper = getattr(content, 'wrapper_css_tag', None)                   
            if current_wrapper is None:                                                   
                if last_wrapper is not None:                                              
                    # close the previous wrapper                                          
                    s += u'</%s>' % last_wrapper[0]                                       
            else:                                                                         
                if last_wrapper is None:                                                  
                    s += u'<%s class="%s">' % current_wrapper                             
                elif last_wrapper != current_wrapper:                                     
                    s += u'</%s><%s class="%s">' % (                                      
                        last_wrapper[0], current_wrapper[0], current_wrapper[1])          

            last_wrapper = current_wrapper                                                
            s += _render_content(content, request=data['request'], context=context)       

        if last_wrapper is not None:                                                      
            s += u'</%s>' % last_wrapper[0]                                               

        return s
```

In your template, instead of `{% feincms_render_region feincms_page 'region' request %}` you would then use `{% cms_render_region feincms_page 'region' request %}` to render the region.

You can adapt the logic of the render template to whatever your trying to accomplish. The content blocks are in `page.content.{{ region }}`, for instance `page.content.sidebar`.